# How to Tag "Start" and "End" while I have repeated values in excel

Tags: excel

How to tag "START" / "END" when value repeats.

I have repeated values in Column U,  I want to automatically tag "START" for the first value and "END" for the second repeated value in excel

**Current Output:**

```
ColumnU   
-6        
-5         
-5
-4
-4
-3
4
4
5
5
6
6
```

**Expected output:**

```
ColumnU   TAG
-6        START
-5        START
-5        END
-4        START
-4        END
-3        START
4         START
4         END
5         START
5         START
6         START
6         END
```

I have used the below formula, it works only for 200 records, apart from 200 it gives me empty cells of 40000 records, how I should fix it and works for all the 40000 records?

**Formula:**

```
=IF(COUNTIF($U:$U, $U2)>=2,IFERROR(CHOOSE(COUNTIF($U$2:U2,U2),"START","END"),""),"")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are testing for `>=2` since it appears the values either appear strictly once (*start*) or twice (*end*).

Therefor, just output `Start` when the count in the range thus far is 1

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)=1,"Start","End")
```

Comment: Even with a dynamic range reference I fear, that many countifs(40,000) would kill the calcs.

Comment: True - will def take some time to calc with this method

Answer (score 1):

IF formula works here..

```
=IF(A2<>A1,"START","END")
```

It's comparing the value to the one above it. This works as long as sorting this way is a workable solution for you. That's how your sample appears, so that's the assumption.

[image]

Comment: How I should reference the cell in the formula (=IF(A2<>A1,"START","END"))? if I have the repeated values in column U2 to U40000

Comment: So swap `A2` for `U2` and `A1` for `U1`... For all answers you have posted here just update the column. We all used `A:A` to test

Answer (score 1):

If your data is not sorted like your example:

```
=IF(MATCH(U2,U:U,0)=ROW(),"START","END")
```